# sqlldr on oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader

I have an assignment in a class which requires the transfering of data from tables in one schema to another using the sqlldr tool. I have set up my control files, and text files(.csv files if you prefer) in order to transfer the data using sqlldr. Now I am using ORACLE 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0. I am all ready to go but when I type in the sqlldr command, or event just "sqlldr" I get the unknown command message. Am i just completely off or does this mean this utility isnt available on this version? I have the ingredients needed to make it happen but I cant figure out why I cant get sqlldr to run. Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction. Below is the specific syntax we were given in class.

sqlldr username/password control=loadsals.ctl

Comment: Are you running that command from the operating system command line?  Or from the `SQL*Plus` command line?  Or something else?  I'm guessing that you are in `SQL*Plus`, in which case you need to exit `SQL*Plus` and run that from the operating system command line.  It's always helpful to be as specific as possible with errors.  "unknown command message" could mean many things but if there is a `SQL*Plus` error code associated with the message, that would certainly imply that you're using `SQL*Plus`.

Comment: Yes I have since run it through the command line and had success at least accessing the sql loader.. sorry silly mistake. However, I get this error   SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified... Not sure what this means.

Answer (score 0):

The user you are logged in under does not have access to SQLLDR.  You will need to elevate your access via sudo or use another login that does have access.